# ASP.NET MVC 3 Music Store Tutorial

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using the MVC Music store tutorial application.
I have changed 3 of the original classnames (renamed them) of the application namely Genre,Album and Artist and have named them as Categories,Brands and Types respectively.

I have updated all the references everywhere. So after this what I have is the same application and database values but with the NAMES which I WANT.

In the **SampleData.cs** which is the seed class, when I add new values to the list as per my requirements, I dont see any changes being reflected in the database and on running the application the same values are displayed again.

MY SEED CLASS CODE SNIPPET (Categories only)

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace MvcMusicStore.Models
{
    public class SampleData : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<MusicStoreEntities>
    {
        protected override void Seed(MusicStoreEntities context)
        {
            var genres = new List<Categories>
            {
               new Categories { Name = "Guitars" },
               new Categories { Name = "Keyboards" },
               new Categories { Name = "Drums" },
               new Categories { Name="Amplifiers"}

            };
```

---

OUTPUT BEING SHOWN :

Rock
Classical
Jazz
Pop 
Disco
Latin
Metal
Alternative 
Reggae
Blues

etc etc..

Also I suppose in the EF Code first approach changes to the seed data would be dynamically reflected in the database which it is connected (The database connection is working fine)

Need some guidance here please.
Thanks in advance

Comment: As far as I can see, you're not saving anything to the database, therefore there's nothing to persist.

Comment: No but sir I guess in MVC EF Code first framework any changes to the seed class needs to be reflected in the database right? All the tables (i.e Categories, brands etc) are already there. Please help me if I am conceptually lagging somewhere. There were values populated already, I am changing those in the seed class which I have shown above.

Comment: Sure, *if* you add it to the database. For now, you're just creating a list of `Categories` without doing something with it.

Comment: Or should I change the line to  

public class SampleData : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<MusicStoreEntities> ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the seeded data to your database context:

```
protected override void Seed(MusicStoreEntities context)
{        
    context.Categries.Add(new Categories { Name = "Guitars" });
    context.Categries.Add(new Categories { Name = "Keyboards" });
    context.Categries.Add(new Categories { Name = "Drums" });
    context.Categries.Add(new Categories { Name="Amplifiers"});

    base.Seed(context);
}
```

Comment: Now when I change the values directly in the database and not even a single value here in the seed class, the website is fetching the right values and displaying it right from the database. So, in this case essentially the seed is having no role to play. May I ask why is that so?

Comment: It's hard to tell what's going on. I don't know the structure of the database, how you modified the data or how you retrieve it. As far as I know, the data should be there, but I don't know how EF reacts in this situation. Just to be sure, add a `context.SaveChanges()` before `base.Seed(context);`. If that doesn't do the trick, you might want to open a new question, maybe someone can explain that to you.

Comment: I very much want to open a new question, in fact its just a little issue left now in development which I can explain pretty well to get it done. But apparently I am not allowed to do do.(OPEN A NEW QUESTION)